# requirejs dependency ordering

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Given the following requirejs definitions on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['path/to/scriptA']);
    require(['path/to/scriptB']);        
</script>
```

**Question 1**: Without assuming dependencies between scriptA and scriptB, is requireJS guaranteed to load scriptA prior to scriptB?

**Question 2**: Assume that scriptA internally defines scriptB as a dependency.  E.g.:

```
// scriptA:
define(['path/to/scriptB'], function(scriptB) {....
```

Is scriptB guaranteed to load prior to prior to scriptA regardless of the ordering of my initial require(..) definitions? Since scriptA defines scriptB as a dependency, should I remove the require(..) call to scriptB from my `<script`> tag?

Comment: I don't think it's guarenteed. I could be wrong, but, have you looked at setting dependancies in the shim config? This will give you the ordering you want http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Comment: Don't confuse "load script before" with "execute module before". I'd expect in both cases that they are loaded in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both scripts should load in parallel. Regarding execution order, the following should be true:

**Question 1**: No, without explicitly defining the dependencies, scriptA is not guaranteed to execute before scriptB.

**Question 2**: Yes, by explicitly defining scriptB as a dependency of scriptA, it will execute first. Considering this, you can indeed remove scriptB from your original script tag.

Hope that helps